# How to change splash screen in Flutter IOS without XCode

Tags: flutter, dart, background-color, splash-screen

I want to change the splash screen for IOS in flutter but I don't have XCode as I am working on Ubuntu 20.0. I changed all the `LaunchImages` in `LaunchImage.imageset` but don't know where to change the background color of the splash screen. How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

My package [flutter_native_splash](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_splash) will allow you to set up a native splash screen without XCode.